# Problem with docker nginx container on host with Apache server

Tags: docker, apache, nginx

I'm running a container with web-app on nginx and have an error bind: address already in use. if I stop apache on host - container runs and all is fine. But I need apache server running on host. I have multiple addresses on host, on container I map one address, apache listens another, in all conf files of sites I set to listen required address, not *:443.
**netstat -pna | grep 443** shows nothing, but **sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep 443** shows this 7 different instancies like this

```
apache2   866686        www-data    6u  IPv6 25980569      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
```

Comment: Start Apache, check which ports and addresses are listened to.  Then stop apache, start nginx.  Collect the same info.  Compare both to see the conflict.

Comment: I know that apache listening 443 port on all addresses, but I can't find where I can stop this. I set required address in all conf files, not *:443, in every point there is x.x.x.x:443. I disabled all sites by a2dissite, but this error still remains

Answer (score -1):

**grep -ir "80" /etc/apache2/ && grep -ir "443" /etc/apache2/**

set my_ip_address:80 and my_ip_address:443 in every instancie of 80 and 443 in every file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).